# spring where to find implementation code of annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth

In spring and spring-boot there is a lot of "magic" that happens just by annotating methods and classes.

For learning purposes and do-it-yourself stuff I would be interested to have a look at them and so wondering how to find the "magic code" that an annotation "causes" ...

1. how to find the magic code in the spring jar classes?
2. atm I am interested like hell how the spring-cloud-sleuth annotation `@NewSpan` "is_implemented" as my manual tries to achieve the same according to http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/single/spring-cloud-sleuth.html#_span_lifecycle look completely different if I have a look at them in the Zipkin UI

is there a "cook-book" on how to find the implementing code of Annotations inside spring jars?

Comment: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/master/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/annotation/NewSpan.java

Comment: The annotations itself don't do anything, they just mark classes and methods for other code. Here they use an aop pointcut (see http://stonefishy.github.io/blog/2015/06/12/spring-aop-dynamic-pointcut/) to find all marked places (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/master/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/annotation/SleuthAdvisorConfig.java#L93) then process them https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/master/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/annotation/SleuthAdvisorConfig.java#L176

Answer (score 0):

You'll find all of it on GitHub.

[Spring Web annotations](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/tree/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation)

[Spring framework annotations](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/tree/master/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation)

[More spring framework annotations](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/tree/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation)